# How does Chrome Driver work, but Firefox, PhantomJS and HTMLUnit not?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver, geckodriver

I am trying to scrape a dynamic content (javascript) page with Python + Selenium + BS4 and the page blocks my requests at random (the soft might be: F5 AMS).

I managed to bypass this thing by changing the user-agent for each of the browsers I have specified. The thing is, **only the Chrome driver can pass over the rejection**. Same code, adjusted for PhantomJS or Firefox drivers is blocked **constantly**, like I am not even changing the user agent.

I must say that I am also multithreading, that meaning, starting 4 browsers at the same time.

Why does this happen? What does Chrome Webdriver have to offer that can pass over the firewall and the rest don't?

I really need to get the results because I want to change to Firefox, therefore, I want to make Firefox pass just as Chrome.

Comment: Some sites have scraping protection, and they can easily detect type of browser, even when you have faked user agent. There are typical differences between Javascript behaviors of each and that can be used to detect your actual browser. The job is protect scraping and I assume they are doing well. It would be hard to know what kind of combinations they are using for this and would required decent research time from your side.

Comment: But what about the hint that the Chrome Driver bypasses the security every time I change the user agent? Can't I use this fact to make Firefox work as well? (knowing that only. changing the user agent in geckodriver didn't work)

Answer (score 1):

Two words: Browser Fingerprinting.  It's a huge topic in it's own right and as Tarun mentioned would take a decent amount of research to nail this issue on its head.  But possible I believe.